# How to mention someone in "on_message"

Tags: python, discord, message, discord.py

So I want to to make the bot to mention the author on author who has said n-word. I've tried to use `{message.mention}` but apparently it does not exist so how does I mention someone using on_message event?
Here is the code:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
  if "ni**a" in message.content:
    await message.channel.send(f"<:sniper:711509974588719216> R6 BRUH {message.author}")
  if 'ni**er' in message.content:
    await message.channel.send(f"<:sniper:711509974588719216> R6 BRUH {message.author}")
  if 'Ni**a' in message.content:
    await message.channel.send(f"<:sniper:711509974588719216> R6 BRUH {message.author}")
  if 'Ni**er' in message.content:
    await message.channel.send(f"<:sniper:711509974588719216> R6 BRUH {message.author}")
```

Comment: You should probably normalize your strings before checking if the word is in the content. It's easy to bypass your bot by simply capitalize every other letter. Try instead to only compare lowercase version by first converting the content to lowercase with `message.content.lower()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mention the author of a message, you can use `message.author.mention`. And also you don't have to do 4 if statements, 1 is enough. Here's what you can do:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
  content = message.content.lower()
  if "ni**a" in content or "ni**er" in content:
    await message.channel.send(f"<:sniper:711509974588719216> R6 BRUH {message.author.mention}")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Member object**

In order to mention someone you need to have the [member object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) associated with that person.

The member object contains an attribute "[mention](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.mention)" which can be used to retrieve the string used to mention that member.

---

**So how to apply this?**

As `message.author` is a member object. We can use `message.author.mention` to get the string to mention that member. Resulting in the following code:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
  if "ni**a" in message.content:
    await message.channel.send(f"<:sniper:711509974588719216> R6 BRUH {message.author.mention}")
  if 'ni**er' in message.content:
    await message.channel.send(f"<:sniper:711509974588719216> R6 BRUH {message.author.mention}")
  if 'Ni**a' in message.content:
    await message.channel.send(f"<:sniper:711509974588719216> R6 BRUH {message.author.mention}")
  if 'Ni**er' in message.content:
    await message.channel.send(f"<:sniper:711509974588719216> R6 BRUH {message.author.mention}")
```

---

**Simplify**

And as some people have mentioned before we can simplify your code to this:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
  content = message.content.lower()
  if "ni**a" in content or "ni**er" in content:
    await message.channel.send(f"<:sniper:711509974588719216> R6 BRUH {message.author.mention}")
```

---

**References:**

[Member object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member)

[Member.mention](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.mention)

[Message object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message)

[Message.content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.content)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mention a user you always have to do this:

```
await message.channel.send(f"blablabliblu------> {message.authormention}")#you want to mention the message author
#mention a other spezific user
user = client/bot.get_user(user_id)#get the user
await message.channel.sedn(f"hellooooooo---> {user.mention})")
#so you alwas need <someuser.mention>
```